# Where is the definition of the sync(2) Linux function call for x86_64 processors

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, glibc, libc

I'm trying to find the **Linux 3.2.21 x86_64** implementation of the [`sync(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) Unix function declared in the *unistd.h* header. Looking at the Linux *unistd.h* yields this prototype:

```
/* Make all changes done to all files actually appear on disk.  */
extern void sync (void) __THROW;
```

So I take that to mean that `sync` is defined outside of the Linux kernel and looking inside **glibc 2.7**, which gives me me this definition in [*glibc-2.17/misc/sync.c*](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.17/misc_2sync_8c_source.html):

```
/* Make all changes done to all files actually appear on disk. */
void
sync ()
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
}
```

So that means `sync` does nothing other than set the value of `errno`.

However, when I disassemble **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a** on system, I find that the *sync* section makes a system call, passing the value `162` (so it is doing something).

Looking at the Linux source again at [arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h?v=3.2#L370), I see:

```
#define __NR_sync               162
__SYSCALL(__NR_sync, sys_sync)
```

Now I'm really confused.

If `sync(2)` is defined outside of Linux, why is there a system call for it? Where is the definition of `sync` for the x86_64 architecture?

**P.S.**: I did find the preprocessor definition of `__SYSCALL` at [arch/x86/kernel/syscall_64.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_64.c?v=3.2#L10), but this seems to imply that the `sync` system call just calls an external function declared as `void sys_sync(void)`. Where is the definition for this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `fs/sync.c`. See:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(sync)
{
...
```

---

The `glibc` version you posted is likely what's compiled in the very awkward case where the kernel doesn't expose a `sync` syscall. In other words it's a stub that's virtually never used.

Comment: I would also suggest to look into http://musl-libc.org/ which is an alternative libc library with a source code much easier to understand than Gnu Libc